# User Mass update

Tags: data-loader, user, user-management, username

I want to mass update username and email address for 4000+ users, and want to make sure that their username gets updated. 
There's only two ways to update username:

1. If User go to link prompted by salesforce on username change and approve that
2. If org admin generates new password for user with username update so username will be updated instantaneously.

Please suggest way (dataloader or anything) to make this change successfully without getting approval for new username from every user.

Note: New password generation is acceptable way to do so, but there are more than 4000 records so doing individually is out of scope.

Comment: I wonder you won't be able to do it without notifying users as it could be a security issue to Salesforce ecosystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue with about 4,000 users.    You'll need to contact SFDC Support and open a case, if you don't own the email domain.   They will disable the email notification for a short period of time.  Also, this will require Executive approval (signed letter sent to SFDC support), so be ready to ask them.

Here's more information below:

> It is possible to suppress the email notification upon changing a
>   user's EMAIL address, but not upon the USERNAME change.   Refer to
>   [Article # 3832](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Disabling-Email-Change-Verification&language=en_US) for information on the process to suppress notification
>   on EMAIL address change.
>
> Workaround: You can Deactivate the User (Do not remove them from any
>   teams).  Change the Username and then reactivate the User.   This will
>   forego the notification email that the Username has been changed.
>   However if there are other emails via Workflows or other triggers that
>   are set to fire upon activation of a User in your org those will need
>   to be deactivated first.  Otherwise those Emails will fire upon
>   activation of the User.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002700&language=en_US

Comment: Seems like it would work for only email domains the company owns?

Comment: We own the domain, we are keeping both domain but for CRM we have another one now, But main issue is with username where to make it generic, we need to update them. I can't deactivate and activate all users one by one for update, that's why I asked help here.

Comment: @AnkzDavé, you can deactivate using dataloader in bulk.  Same for updating user names and reactivating.  The field you need to reference is "isActive" on the User object

Answer (score 1):

You can request [disable email verification for a domain](https://na1.salesforce.com/_ui/training/help/pub/UserEdSolution?id=50130000000MJ1h&retURL=https%3A%2F%2Fna7.salesforce.com%2F_ui%2Ftraining%2Fhelp%2FCombinedSearchPage%3Fstr%3DEmail%2Bchange%2Bwithout%2Bconfirmation&ps=1&orgId=00D000000000062). This only applies if you own the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try login with System Administrator profile and push User records via dataloader.
Also, I tried it for single user via System Admin login and no approval is required for Admin, the only thing to keep in mind is that the username should be unique across all salesforce orgs globally.